# Integrating Factors for nonexact differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{x^2 + y + 2}{x}.$$

I want to make the function exact first

My steps:

$$\big(x^2 + y + 2\big)\,dx - x\,dy = 0$$

$(My - Nx)/N = 2/x,$ which is the integrating factor.

After integrating this as an exponent of $e$, I got $2/x.$

I then multiplied it into the obtained second equation to give the following equation:

$$\big(x^4 + x^2y + 2x^2\big)\,dx - x^3\,dy = 0.$$

I then checked if it was exact and it was not. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Actually, you should have a negative sign:
$$\frac{M_y-N_x}{N}=-\frac{2}{x}$$
The integrating factor will be $\mu(x)=e^{\int -\frac{2}{x}~dx}$. What integrating factor do you obtain in this case?

Comment: How did you get the negative?

Comment: We have that $M_y=1$, $N_x=-1$, $N=-x$, so:
$$\frac{1-(-1)}{-x}=\frac{2}{-x}=-\frac{2}{x}$$

Comment: Ok I mislabeled it on my paper. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can approach it differently. Precisely, you can make use of the integrating factor method:
\begin{align*}
& y^{\prime} = x + \frac{y}{x} + \frac{2}{x} \Longleftrightarrow y^{\prime} - \frac{y}{x} = x + \frac{2}{x} \Longleftrightarrow \frac{y^{\prime}}{x} - \frac{y}{x^{2}} = 1 + \frac{2}{x^{2}} \Longleftrightarrow\\\\
&\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)^{\prime} = 1 + \frac{2}{x^{2}} \Longleftrightarrow \frac{y}{x} = x - \frac{2}{x} + k\Longleftrightarrow y = x^{2} - 2 + kx
\end{align*}

Comment: What happened to the y/(x^2) when you moved to the last step?

Comment: I included it in the derivative

$$\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)^{\prime}$$